# What does this clojure.core.typed type error mean?

Tags: types, clojure, clojure-core.typed

I want to get the `clojure.core.typed` type check passing, but I'm getting a type error that I don't understand.

My questions are:

- What does the error below mean?
- How can I fix it?

Here is my code (which I realize is incorrect):

```
(ns clj.util.map
  (:require [clojure.core.typed :as t]))

(t/ann map-vals
       (All [k v1 v2]
            (Fn [ (Fn [(t/Option v1) -> (t/Option v2)])
                  (t/Option (t/Map k v1)) ->
                  (t/Option (t/Map k v2)) ])))

(defn map-vals
  ;; FIXME: Incorrect code
  "Apply a function to each of the values in a map, returning the updated map."
  [f hm]
  (t/doseq> [k :- Any (keys hm)]
            (assoc hm k (f (get hm k)))))
```

Here is the output of `lein typed check clj.util.map`:

```
Initializing core.typed ...
"Elapsed time: 6697.604 msecs"
core.typed initialized.
Start collecting clj.util.map
Finished collecting clj.util.map
Collected 1 namespaces in 6851.111 msecs
Start checking clj.util.map
Checked clj.util.map in 968.041 msecs
Checked 1 namespaces (approx. 21 lines) in 7823.552 msecs
Type Error (clj.util.map:14:23) Polymorphic function clojure.core/keys could not be applied to arguments:
Polymorphic Variables:
    k

Domains:
    (t/Map k Any)

Arguments:
    (t/Option (t/Map k v1))

Ranges:
    (t/Seq k) :object {:path [Keys], :id 0}

in: (clojure.core/keys hm)
in: (clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/keys hm))


Type Checker: Found 1 error
Found errors
Subprocess failed
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first part of the error tells you this concerns a call to `clojure.core/keys`. You can lookup the type with `(cf keys)`.

`(All [k]
   [(Map k Any) -> (Seq k) :object {:id 0 :path [Keys]}])`

The error is basically summarising this polymorphic type juxtaposed with the actual types provided to the function.

The `Polymorphic Variables` list all the variables in the `All` binder and their type bounds. `k` is the only variable, which has essentially no bounds, so `k` is displayed.

The `Domains` list all the parameter types (to the left of the `->`) in order. If multiple arities were specified with `Fn`, each parameter list would be displayed sequentially.

The `Arguments` show you what types are *actually* passed to the function. The code at 14:23 is presumably this call `(keys hm)`, so the type of the first argument is displayed:  `(t/Option (t/Map k v1))`

The `Ranges` list all the return types (to the right of the `->`) in order.

Sometimes there is an `Expected` type, which must match up with a `Range` in the same way all the `Arguments` must match up with a `Domain`.

We can diagnose this error by comparing the `Domains` with the `Arguments`. The list of `Arguments` must fit under one list of `Domains`, and the match is attempted top-down. If no `Domains` fit with the `Arguments`, we get a type error like this; it's often too complicated to pinpoint exactly where the constraint algorithm failed, so the user is presented with a lot of information.

In this case, we try and fit the argument `(t/Option (t/Map k v1))` under the domain `(t/Map k Any)`, which fails. This is because the argument `(t/Option (t/Map k v1))` is the same as `(U nil (t/Map k v1))`, and `nil` does not fit under the domain `(t/Map k Any)`.

There are a couple of ways to fix this. You basically need to ensure `keys` isn't passed `nil`. Here's one option:

`(keys (or hm {}))`

Comment: Great explanation; makes total sense. Thanks for that, and for your excellent work on `clojure.core.typed`!